# Add parameter to authorizeResource

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8.

I wrote an API using the resources. For the authorizations I wrote this for each method (example for the 'store' method):

```
public function store(StoreSiteTypeRequest $request, Organization $organization)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', [SiteType::class, $organization]);
        .....
    }
```

It works fine. But by doing this, I realize that the validations are still executed.

So an unauthorized user who posts something wrong will get a response with errors. And ideally this user should get an "unauthorized" response.

In the documentation I read that resources can also be secured in the constructor of the class. Like this:

```
public function __construct(SiteTypeRepository $siteTypeRepository, Organization $organization)
    {
        $this->siteTypeRepository = $siteTypeRepository;
        $this->authorizeResource(SiteType::class, 'site-type');
    }
```

Is it better to secure these resources like that?

For my case, I need to add the "organization" parameter for the policy.

I tried a lot of things:

```
$this->authorizeResource(SiteType::class, 'site-type', $organization);
$this->authorizeResource(SiteType::class, ['site-type', $organization]);
$this->authorizeResource(SiteType::class, null, ['site-type', $organization]);
```

without success.

How to add this parameter?

### Edit

I found a solution, but tell me if it could be the good solution:

In the policy class, I can retrieve the "organization" from the URL, like that:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->organization = request()->route()->parameter('organization');
    }
```

And in the update of the policy, I can do only:

```
public function update(User $user)
    {
        return $user->role_id === 'ADMIN' && $user->organization_id === $this->organization->id;
    }
```

And at least in the controller, I only have to write that:

```
$this->authorizeResource(SiteType::class, 'site_type');
```

without this extra parameter I wanted to add.

It works fine. But as I have about 20 controllers to modify, I would like to be sure that this solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Users having to fill out the correct details only to find out that they are not authorization anyway would be poor UX. So ideally, authorization should happen prior to the form validation.

Since you are already using form request validation, you could move the authorization logic into the `authorize()` method within the `StoreSiteTypeRequest` class which should do the trick.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests

Comment: Yes P.K. , it could be also a solution. But I prefer keep all the policies logic in the same class. With your possibility, this logic should be splitted (a small part in the form request, another part in policy class). For the moment I am waiting a little , I'm still thinking ... But thanks for your response.